# Unable to put RAR message in default section for Seagull Network Generator tool

Tags: wireshark, diameter-protocol, telecom

I am using Seagull Tool, to test Functionality of RAR,RAA in between PCRF and PCEF system, If i put RAR portion in traffic section, i can see PCRF is generating RAR and RAA is also being populated, and further call flow of PCRF is being continued as expected, the moment I kept RAR portion in default rather than in traffic , i am getting below error message in seagull log:

2023-09-06.09:58:36.737|W|No definition found for [285]
2023-09-06.09:58:36.738|T|Received a message (while not in receive state) for call with session-id [ 54 55 52 4b 5f 72 63 31 36 5f 65 76 72 5f 63 68 65 63 6b 5f 31 30 32 ]
2023-09-06.09:58:36.738|T|Switching to default scenario

After RAA is being processed no further call flow of CCR-U CCA-U is not happening

Expected result , whenever I do some API operation for the subscriber , PCRF will generate RAR, in response PCEF sends RAA, while keeping RAR related info in default section and post RAA , session should continue ,
At present once RAA is processed, in wireshark observed no CCR-U, CCA-U is passing